# Downgraded Angular2 component not rendered inside angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

We have a unique situation where we use typescript, mixing ng1 and 2, but not using any module loader. I was able to bootstrap both ng 1 and ng2, but i cant get any response from downgraded angular 2 component, i put a break point inside the code and saw that the code runs, but the component doesn't show anything.

I don't get any errors, not in compilation phase and not in runtime.

Here's the code:

**myapp.js** - angular 1 app definition, es2015

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', []);
})();
```

**myapp.ng2.ts** - angular 2 app definition, typescript

```
namespace MyApp {

let NgModule = ng.core.NgModule;
let BrowserModule = ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule;
let UpgradeAdapter = ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter;

@NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule]
})

export class MyAppNg2 {}

export const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter(MyAppNg2);

$(document).ready(function() {
    upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['MyApp'], {strictDi: false});
});

}
```

**fullDetails.component.ts** - angular 2, typescript

```
namespace MyApp.Components.Misc {

    let Component = ng.core.Component;

    @Component({
        selector: 'full-details-header',
        template: `This is ng2 component`
    })

    export class FullDetailsHeaderComponent {
    }

}
```

**bootstrap.js** - angular1, es2015

```
angular.module('myApp').component('fullDetailsHeader', MyApp.upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(MyApp.Components.Misc.FullDetailsHeaderComponent));
```

Comment: did you found any solution on that?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to say since I think this is for the beta version of Angular, which I haven't done an upgrade process with, but for Angular versions 2+ you also need to declare your component that you want downgraded in the `entryComponents` array of your main module:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule],
   entryComponents: [FullDetailsHeaderComponent]
})
```

Assuming this was for the Angular beta, and you don't have much working, I would scrap this and use the latest version of Angular and follow the [official guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html).  There is just too much that is different in the examples I see for creating an ng1/ng2 hybrid app between the beta and release versions of Angular that I don't feel it's worth troubleshooting problems related to the beta upgrade process.

This is still a fairly difficult area to search for questions and examples on, so if you have a question related to the upgrade process for Angular versions 2+ make a new question and ping me.

To get your started, here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6SFy7nbK6TgtfQ44tMfs?p=preview) which shows a working example of downgrading an Angular component and using it in AngularJS.  This also uses multiple transclusion in the downgrade process which only works in versions 4.0.0+.